# Why does the compiler warn me of “control reaching end of non-void function”?

Tags: objective-c

I have declared a method in animal.h file

```
-(id)initWithName:(NSString *)n description:(NSString *)d url:(NSString *)u;
```

and i have implemented this method in animal.m file like

```
-(id)initWithName:(NSString *)n description:(NSString *)d url:(NSString *)u
{
    self.name=n;
    self.description=d;
    self.imageURL=u;

}
```

but at the end of file it shows warning like "Control reaches end of non-void function"

can anyone tell me what is the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

init Method Should return object Reference ..
so ,

```
-(id)initWithName:(NSString *)n description:(NSString *)d url:(NSString *)u
{

  self.name=n;

  self.description=d;

  self.imageURL=u;

  return self;

}
```

Answer (score 9):

The return type of your method is `id`. But your are returning nothing. This is an error as the compiler said.

Btw: This init method has a lot of flaws. You should change it to:

```
-(id)initWithName:(NSString *)n description:(NSString *)d url:(NSString *)u
{
    if ((self = [super init])) {
        self.name=n;
        self.description=d;
        self.imageURL=u;
    }
    return self;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the animal class is a subclass of NSObject, and the method is an initializer here's what the method should look like

```
-(id)initWithName:(NSString *)n description:(NSString *)d url:(NSString *)u
{
    if(self = [super init]){
        self.name=n;
        self.description=d;
        self.imageURL=u;
    }
    return self;
}
```